# How to redefine Windows-S shortcut in Microsoft OneNote 2010

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2010

Microsoft OneNote 2010 has an option when pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd> -<kbd>S</kbd> activates taking screenshot. Now in `Windows 8.1` they decided to break this functionality (as they always like to do).

Is it possible to redefine screenshot shortcut in OneNote 2010?

Comment: have you read http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-onenote/archive/2013/06/27/try-windows-8-1-preview-and-bring-back-your-favorite-shortcut-key.aspx

Comment: Yes this is an answer, please post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A link to external answers are not popular - so I'll quote the text from [this blog](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-onenote/archive/2013/06/27/try-windows-8-1-preview-and-bring-back-your-favorite-shortcut-key.aspx) here:-

> 1. Use Windows + R to pull up the "run" dialog, and type regedit.
> 2. Now in the folders on the left, navigate down this path:
>
>    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\OneNote\Options\Other
>
> Note: The path requires the specific version of Office. In the path
>   above, 15.0 refers to Office 2013. If you're using Office 2010, type
>   14.0 in place of 15.0 at the end of the path.  Replace 15.0 with 12.0 if you're using Office 2007.
>
> 3. In the folder named Other, right-click the white space underneath the files in that folder and select New, then select DWORD (32-bit)
>      Value.
> 4. In the text entry field that pops up, type ScreenClippingShortcutKey. You just created a new DWORD. (If you are
>      in Office 12.0, this DWORD will already exist.)
> 5. Right click this DWORD and select Modify, then in the Value field, type 41.
>
> Your new shortcut key has been assigned to Windows + A. Now log off
>   and log on again and you should be all set!
>
> Remember, the Windows + Shift + S fix is coming later this year, but
>   hopefully this will help you out until then!